# ajax search box sending last input when input deleted very quickly

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, search, livesearch

So i have an ajax live search that worked perfectly when i was testing it locally, but know that i have it 'live', it will send the last input detected when the input is deleted very quickly.

(by very quickly i mean delete key held down, tapped alot, or even sumtimes a ctrl+a and delete will trigger bug.)

It does do it consistently I think that the function is firing when the delete key is pressed however changing the function from keyup to keypress does not work and removes my animations.

the console tells me that the search box is empty in length and value.

EDIT: i could not resolve the issue with the delete key sending the last input to the server, so i made a cosmetic solution using .show() and .hide()

solution in answers

Comment: Sounds like you need to delay firing off another AJAX request, disable the input temporarily or perhaps just set a flag indicating a particular ajax response is no longer wanted and shouldn't be rendered. Also, the keydown event will give you a little longer to submit the request and receive the response, since action has started before they've even lifted a finger from the key.

Comment: @enhzflep seems reasonable to me...although im not sure how i would delay the request /.\ mind showing me a snippet??

Comment: Sure, I'll put something together when I get home. In the meantime, you can get the current system time in milliseconds when your code signals an ajax should be fired. Then, next time you need to fire an ajax, you can simply check to see if enough time has elapsed since last time. If so, fire it off. Otherwise, just use a single-shot timer, setTimeout with the 2nd param equal to the remaining time of the 'lock-out' period. I'll be home in a couple of hours,

Answer (score 0):

as stated in edit this is a cosmetic solution

i tried placing setTimeouts inside various places of the function to no avail

this solution uses two if statements to track the value of searchbox and hide/show resultbox accordingly

```
if($('#searchbox').val() === ''){
    $('#resultbox').hide();
}

if($('#searchbox').val() != ''){
    $('#resultbox').show();
}
```